# C++ condition variable wait, does the wait block if the predicate is already true?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, deadlock, condition-variable

Here I am the Writer worker thread, I want to know if the main Reader thread has reached the PrepDone state.

```
  mylock.lock();
  m_writer_cv.wait (mylock, [this]
      {
          return this->m_reader_state == ReaderState::PrepDone;
      }
  );
  m_writer_state = WriterState::BlockWriteDone;
  mylock.unlock();
  m_reader_cv.notify_one();
```

And below I am the reader, there I want to know if if Writer reached WriteDone.

```
              mylock.lock();
              m_reader_state = ReaderState::PrepDone;
              m_reader_cv.wait(mylock, [this]
                    {
                        return this->m_writer_state == WriterState::BlockWriteDone;
                    }
              );
              mylock.unlock();
              m_writer_cv.notify_one();
```

Obvious, a hung like situation is observed, its like each is waiting for the other, and neither calling the respective notify_one().
Appreciate any feedback thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: It won't wait.

This:

```
  mylock.lock();
  m_writer_cv.wait (mylock, [this]
      {
          return this->m_reader_state == ReaderState::PrepDone;
      }
  );
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
  mylock.lock();
  while !(this->m_reader_state == ReaderState::PrepDone) {
      m_writer_cv.wait(mylock);
  };
```

To avoid your race condition, change this:

```
          mylock.lock();
          m_reader_state = ReaderState::PrepDone;
```

To do an initial notify the moment the initial m_reader_state variable is set.

```
          mylock.lock();
          m_reader_state = ReaderState::PrepDone;
          m_writer_cv.notify_one(); // signal the other thread
```

Answer (score 2):

A condition variable `wait` function that takes a predicate will only block while the predicate is `false`. It will never wait when the predicate is `true`. Because you call `wait` holding the associated lock, a race condition is not possible. This is the entire point of condition variables.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, it seems, at some point, m_writer_cv.notify() actually never reached the Writer because it was not at that 'receiving point'. Bascially PrepDone was never reached, so Writer was indefinitely waiting.  I worked around by putting a sleep of 1 ms, and m_write_cv.notify() calling in a loop, then everything worked. May be I need a std::barrier to be sure both are ready to exchange the notifies.

Comment: @AntonFernando Just use the condition variable correctly and you don't need anything else. If the thread that calls `wait` isn't at the rreceiving point, it won't call `wait`, so no harm is done.